# how to find out the number of reroutes in a step-by-step navigation?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm new to Mapbox development. I'm wondering if there is a way to find out how many reroutes occurred in one navigation? Any example in iOS/Swift would be even better. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the `RouteControllerDidReroute` [notification](https://docs.mapbox.com/archive/ios/navigation/api/0.8.1/Notifications.html#/s:16MapboxNavigation25RouteControllerDidRerouteSo14NSNotificationC4NameVv)

For extra data and more information you can register to the relevant `delegate: RouterDelegate` methods of the [RouteController](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/api/1.0.0/Protocols/RouterDelegate.html)

Mainly the `func router(_ router: Router, willRerouteFrom location: CLLocation)`

Which according to the documentation:

> Called immediately before the router calculates a new route.
>
> This method is called after router(*:shouldRerouteFrom:) is called, and before router(*:didRerouteAlong:) is called.

Lastly, if one uses the default `NavigationViewController` supplied by Mapbox.
You can register as it's delegate (`NavigationViewControllerDelegate`) to get the following updates:

`func navigationViewController(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, willRerouteFrom location: CLLocation?)`

`func navigationViewController(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, didRerouteAlong route: Route)`